# Trouble updating original item in list from object reference retrieved in dictionary

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, clone

I have a redux like state tree that looks as such (reduced down for readability).

```
public class StateTree : StateBase
{
      public List<News> News;
      public List<Opinion> Opinions;
}
```

I cannot mutate an object, I must replace it, because the `StateBase` I am using has a bunch of logic that requires you to not mutate (similar to redux).

These objects have visual representations that I am dragging and dropping.  My visual objects are `UIObject` and they represent a domain object, which can be one of several types.  I created an `IMoveable` interface for my domain objects that can be dragged and dropped (through a `UIObject`)

I have no control over the `UIObject` creation so when a `UIObject` is dropped I dont have a link directly to my domain object.  As such I have tried to create a `Dictionary<UIObject, IMoveable>`

I can now find my `IMoveable` (domain object), but I do not know where in the state tree it is. I could for loop over each item in each list in my `StateTree` and check if it's the item and if so replace that array index with a new item.  I would prefer not to do that.

Here is my drag end, where I get the domain object and pass it on to my reducer. (Just a function that returns a new state)

```
IMoveable Actor = movementManager.GetIMoveableFromDroppedObject(droppedObject);

Store.Dispatch<MoveableAction>(new MoveableAction() {
    ActionType = "MoveObject", ObjectPosition = ObjectPosition, Actor = Actor 
});
```

This store dispatch gets picked up and does the following

```
        public override StateTree Reduce(StateTree state, MoveableAction action)
        {
            switch (action.ActionType)
            {
                case "MoveObject":

                  var moveable = action.Actor;
                  IMoveable obj = (IMoveable)moveable.Clone();
                  obj.UpdatePosition(action.ObjectPosition);
                  moveable = obj;
                break;
            }
        return state;
        }
```

This doesn't seem to function as expected, the original `List` that contains the `IMoveable` I found in my dictionary is unaffected.   I thought these objects were passed by ref and therefore I could just replace it but it seems to not be so simple. Is there a way to accomplish what I want to do, or am I forced to go through every possible list/type and do a comparison?

Comment: There isn't any code here in which you alter the dictionary. So with that said, how are you trying to replace the value in the dictionary itself? Just setting `moveable=obj;` wouldn't alter the dictionary if the values are immutable, as no reference to the `Dictionary` object is created.

Comment: Yeah @Tronald  the dictionary is just meant to be like a cache of items in the various lists in the tree.  So, state tree has 5 lists of diff objects. 
I put them all in one dictionary so I can find those objects without going through the 5 lists.  From that dictionary item I want to overwrite the object such that if I were to check the original lists or the dictionary that object would be changed

Comment: I suppose I thought that when I get the item from the dictionary I get a ref to the object.  So if I set that object equal to a new ref everything that points to that object would have updated objects..

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now regarding the lists. Regarding dictionary, that would normally be the case for mutable objects, but immutable's don't work that way. This fiddle shows an example: [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dgvNOQ). Because of this, you will have to manually replace the item in the dictionary.

Comment: @Tronald I tried updating the dictionary, and the dictionary updated, but all the lists that reference that items in the dictionary remain unupdated.  

I don't know which list a given item is in and each list is its own type, the dictionary just serves to give me one place to look to get back an item (by a common interface so I don't have to know the type/list).  What I really want is for the item in the dictionary, which is also in some list, get updated in both places.